# Loading webpack chunks dynamically

Tags: webpack

There are couple of similar questions in StackOverflow, but I haven't really found answer and seems like it should be possible. Here is what I am trying to achieve:

My application is split into multiple chunks by webpack (I use es6 modules). Then during runtime I want to load chunks as needed (example: when user navigates to a specific page, he first needs to load javascript for that page and then execute callback). I think this concept was pioneered in GWT (but I might be wrong).

Currently in init.js generated by webpack I see following code:

```
/******/    // This file contains only the entry chunk.
/******/    // The chunk loading function for additional chunks
/******/    __webpack_require__.e = function requireEnsure(chunkId, callback) {
/******/        // "0" is the signal for "already loaded"
/******/        if(installedChunks[chunkId] === 0)
/******/            return callback.call(null, __webpack_require__);

/******/        // an array means "currently loading".
/******/        if(installedChunks[chunkId] !== undefined) {
/******/            installedChunks[chunkId].push(callback);
/******/        } else {
/******/            // start chunk loading
/******/            installedChunks[chunkId] = [callback];
/******/            var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
/******/            var script = document.createElement('script');
/******/            script.type = 'text/javascript';
/******/            script.charset = 'utf-8';
/******/            script.async = true;

/******/            script.src = __webpack_require__.p + "" + chunkId + "." + ({"0":"app","1":"otherapp"}[chunkId]||chunkId) + ".js";
/******/            head.appendChild(script);
/******/        }
/******/    };
```

And it seems like that's exactly what I need. There are couple of problems though. First of all, requireEnsure function is not exposed to my application and the second problem is that even if I expose it manually (by injecting my code inside), it doesn't quite work as I would expect right way as it prefixes .js with chunkId + "." which turns out to duplicate module name while fetching javascript: ..js. Here is line I am talking about:

```
script.src = __webpack_require__.p + "" + chunkId + "." + ({"0":"app","1":"otherapp"}[chunkId]||chunkId) + ".js";
```

Is there a way to accomplish it?

Answer (score -1):

You seem to be looking for [code splitting](http://webpack.github.io/docs/code-splitting.html).

In short, you have to explicitly state in the code that things are conditional, e.g. wrap the import (not es6 imports as they have to be at the top level, but CommonJS er RequireJS) in an `if`, or use `require.ensure`.

[This](https://blog.madewithlove.be/post/webpack-your-bags/) blog post might also be of help to you.

Comment: The es6 module syntax includes dynamic import now.